# Match a text for extract values using Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, pattern-matching

For this text:

```
 https://twitter.com/Guardiola31337/status/719108651781332994 …
<li >< a target="_blank" href =" https://twitter.com/gdgbarcelona ">< i class="fa fa-twitter" >< / i><  /a>< /li>
<li >< a target="_blank" href=" https://twitter.com/gdgcaceres "><i class="fa fa-twitter">< / i >< /a ></ li >
< li >< a target="_blank" href =" https://twitter.com/decharlas " >< i class="fa fa-twitter">< / i></a ></ li >
<li> < a target="_blank" href = " https://twitter.com/gdggranada " > < i class="fa fa-twitter" >< / i>< /a >< /li >
```

How can I Extract https://twitter.com/{value} ?

I try this, but I get errors:

```
$text | Select-String "(https://twitter.com/)((?:[A-Za-z0-9-_]*))" -AllMatches |
        Foreach {$_.Matches} | Foreach { $usernames2 += "-" + $_.Value}


$text -match '(https://twitter.com/)((?:[A-Za-z0-9-_]*))'
```

Comment: Did you try escaping the `/`? Try this: `"(https:\/\/twitter.com\/)((?:[A-Za-z0-9-_]*))"`

Comment: How do you fetch the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work for you: `https:\/\/twitter\.com\/([^"]+)` 
[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/oO6iW8/2).

Example:

```
$fetchTwitterPath = 'https:\/\/twitter\.com\/([^"]+)'

[regex]::Matches($text, $fetchTwitterPath) | foreach { $_.Groups.Value[1].Trim() }
```

Output:

```
Guardiola31337/status/719108651781332994
gdgbarcelona
gdgcaceres
decharlas
gdggranada
```

Note: I added a `"`to the first line of your example because it was missing.

Comment: `https:\/\/twitter\.com\/([^"\s]+)` Don't forget the whitespace

Comment: I didn't - I use the Trim() function to get rid of any whitespace ;-)